# Batch file not working properly if I re run from a new command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have written a batch file for cleaning up the recovery files for one of my project work for testing. The script is explained below:

1. It will run an executable which takes a dll file as an argument and then run a process.
2. If the process is killed before doing some calculation, it creates recovery file.
3. Here my script will always load the dll after cleaning up the recovery files to avoid manually deleting the files by visiting a particular path.
4. To make generic, batch script will store the dll path and dll name in text files from where it will automatically pick the path.

Below is the batch script code:

```
@echo off
::Display the information first time if variables not set. Store them for future retrieval
set "currPath=%cd%"
if exist dllPath.txt (
    set /p dllPath<=dllPath.txt
) else (
    set /p dllPath="Provide game dll path (1st time only): "
    ::save the environment variables
    echo %dllPath% > "dllPath.txt"
)

if exist dllName.txt (
    set /p dllName<=dllName.txt
) else (
    set /p dllName="Provide game dll name (1st time only): "
    ::save the environment variables
    echo %dllName% > "dllName.txt"
)


::clean the data
cd /D %dllPath%
@echo %dllPath%
del *.bin
del *.recovery

%dllPath%\..\..\RunProcess.exe -dll %dllPath%\%dllName% 
cd /D %currPath%
```

**Issue with the script**

1. First time on running the script from a command prompt, script is able to properly store the dll path and name properly in a text file.
2. If I run the script multiple times from the same command prompt, the process will run successfully.
3. But if I close the command prompt after running the script and try to run the script from newly opened command prompt, the script will throw error as

*The syntax of the command is incorrect.*

I tried to google about this and try to fix it, but couldn't. This may be a silly question to ask, but being novice in batch scripting I don't have any other option.

Comment: Comment out the `@echo off` in the first line. It will allow you to figure out what line is failing, at which point you can try to figure out why. Blindly running around in the dark trying to guess isn't going to work out well.

Comment: I did that also and came to know the while reading the text files in if case, it is throwing error.

Comment: First, don't add details in comments, but [edit] the post to add them there instead. Second, you have two separate `if` statements, so your added detail doesn't help much.

Comment: oops, my fault. Thank you for correcting me. :)

Comment: Three issues I see: First, the `<=` should be `=<` as others have commented. Second, putting `::` comments in a `block` (parenthesised series of lines) leads to problems as a label is illegal in a block and a `::` comment is actually a label (use the conventional `REM ` instead) Third, since you haven't got a `setlocal` in your code, which customarily follows the `@echo off`, any environment variable established in one run will remain set to that value for further runs in the same `cmd` instance. This actually seems to indicate that the effect should be quite different, but may be related

Comment: @Magoo Thank you for your comments. It helped me in fixing the issue. It's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the `=` before the `<`.

```
set /p dllName=<dllName.txt
```